# Drupal node form custom button

Tags: php, drupal-7

I have a custom button to save and redirect node to a custom page to preview. The content type has paragraph fields embedded. If any validation error occurs in paragraph fields, my custom button is not rendering when the node form showing error. After refreshing the page, it is appearing in the node form.
Can anyone help me?
This is the form_alter code and custom submit handler.

```
 function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
     if($form_id == 'form_id') {
      $link =  "link";
      $form['previewbtn'] = array(
                '#type' => 'button', 
                '#value' => t('Preview'), 
                '#weight' => 9,
                '#submit' => array('custom_submit'),
                '#name' => 'preview_btn',
                '#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,
            );
    function custom_submit($form, &$form_state) {
      $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state); 
      node_save($node);
      $link = "link";
      $form_state['redirect'] = $link;
      unset($_GET['destination']);
      drupal_static_reset('drupal_get_destination');
      drupal_redirect_form($form_state);  
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: More detail about your code and any errors would make it easier for people to help.